# Bad operand types for binary operator "!=" first type int[] second type int

Tags: java, loops, input

I have a exercise with the requirement:

> If the input from the user is equal to an int in my array (generates
>   random numbers every time) the user wins.

I have tried this:

```
Scanner attack = new scanner(system.in);
System.out.println("enter number");
String Attack = attack.nextLine();
Int number = Interger.parseInt(Attack);

//the error lies here

For(int i = number; DragonArray != i ; number++){}
```

I need help on how to loop through my array that generates numbers to see if the user input is equal to any number in the array

Comment: Wouldn't you want to check the index against the length of the array if you're looping through the array liked this? Comparing an integer against an array is non-sensical. Also please consider using the formatting tools to format code as code.

Comment: The length of the array is the amount if characters in the users name

Comment: This can't compile. "Int" should be "int". "For" should be "for." Case matters.

Comment: Thats how it is in my code yes

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, the type of the `DragonArray` is array and i has type as integer. The error here is pretty clear. Since `DragonArray != i` has two different types, it will throw compile time error. The boolean operators can be used to compare same types only. Both the variables here should be of type `int`.

Comment: Okay can you suggest a way for me to loop through the array to see if the user input is at anytime equal to a int in the array